# ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting while migrating manage.py file in Django

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

I am following the Django official documentation for writing my first app using Django.

Here, it says that I have to set `TIME_ZONE` to my time zone in the `settings.py` file.

The default value of `TIME_ZONE` was `"utc"` and i have changed it to `"utc+6.00"`.

After this edit, when I try to migrate the `manage.py` file:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

A value error occurred:

> ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: UTC+6.00

I am sorry, if this is a very basic question, but I couldn't figure out the solution after hours of search in Google.

N.B:

My time zone is **Asia/Dhaka** (+6:00)

My OS is Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone):

> `TIME_ZONE`
>
> Default: 'America/Chicago'
>
> A string representing the time zone for this installation, or None.

Instead of `utc+6.00`, set the `TIME_ZONE` to `Asia/Dhaka`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'
```

Comment: Does that mean, I have to drop the project and re-create it? Suppose, I have created cookie-cutter project with incorrect time zone, then I cannot correct it later then?

Answer (score 11):

In simple words you need to choose your timezone from this  [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 0):

## Cygwin: install "tzdata" package

I'm running MobaXterm (a Cygwin flavor) and so my /usr/share/zoneinfo directory was empty.

And then Django wouldn't start properly.

I fixed this by installing the [`tzdata`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=%2Ftzdata%2F&arch=x86_64) package.

That populated the zoneinfo directory nicely...

```
$ tree /usr/share/zoneinfo | head
/usr/share/zoneinfo
├── Africa
│   ├── Abidjan
│   ├── Accra
│   ├── Addis_Ababa
│   ├── Algiers
│   ├── Asmara
│   ├── Asmera
│   ├── Bamako
│   ├── Bangui
```

...and then Django started up fine.